# Convert Google's SavedModel to Apple's mlmodel

Tags: ios, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine, coreml

This week Apple [announced](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc17/703) support for trained ML models.

How can one convert a trained Tensorflow model (Google Cloud Machine Learning Engine model in SavedModel format) into an Apple [Core ML](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml) model (.mlmodel format)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what your TensorFlow model contains. The coremltools do not support TensorFlow so you'll have to write your own converter. But this will only work if your model only contains things that are supported by the mlmodel format. You can download the spec for this format from the coremltools web page. Since it's possible to build compute graphs of arbitrary complexity in TensorFlow, it's not surprising that coremltools currently does not support it (since mlmodel itself only supports a limited number of model types).

Comment: Thank you for answering.  Apple appears to support InceptionV3, so if one has merely retrained InceptionV3 (as per  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/flowers), you think a converter can be written, correct?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to write a converter for (a retrained) Inception-v3, but it's hard to say how Apple converted their Inception -- did they use the coremltools or using some custom script? Who knows...

Comment: @ChuckFinley did you make some progress?

Comment: No, because of other priorities. The answer is to hire @MatthijsHollemans to write a converter.

Answer (score 0):

You should use coremltools (python package).

Check out the [WWDC Session 710 Video "Core ML In Depth"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/710/)